# Wowza - upload recording to AWS S3 bucket using c#/Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wowza

I have a VM, which I am calling into Wowza to start and stop recording of a stream using their Rest API.

When I stop recording, I would like to then  upload the stream recording to a chosen location on S3.  I was wondering if there was a way to do this programatically as I cannot see any documentation around this.

Anther potential option I thought would be to use the Java based software talked about in this link to upload all streams automatically to an S3 bucket.  I would then need to move the appropriate files to the correct buckets on AWS.

https://www.wowza.com/blog/automate-your-wowza-streaming-engine-vod-workflow-with-amazon-s3

I would prefer a way to specify the folder location and upload directly to their but I am not sure if this is possible.

I am using c# and have downloaded the AWSSDK .net library.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try parameter name "s3UploadFilePrefix"